# Reverse engineering a stored procedure running on SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, sql-server-2000

I need help with a stored procedure I am a complete and utter noob when it comes to databases. I have a program that a client needs to have fixed, it was made by another developer that the client can't seem to get in touch with.

This clients owns this program and has granted me full rights to do whatever I like with it. The problem is that this program uses Crystal Reports, and one specific report that is giving me trouble is ***StockAndSales***. This report is populated from a stored procedure. But the problem is that even after emptying all the tables in the database the report still shows some fields that shouldn't exist.

The program is a .net based application.

And sorry for this noobish post but I am new here.

P.S this procedure is not written by me!

The procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStockAndSales
   @StartDate Varchar(10),
   @EndDate Varchar(10)
As 
Begin

SELECT     T1.Item, dbo.Items.Name, T2. NetPPrice, SUM(T1.O) AS O, SUM(T1.P1) AS P1,     SUM(T1.P2) AS P2, SUM(T1.P3) AS P3, SUM(T1.S1) AS S1, SUM(T1.S2) AS S2, SUM(T1.S3) AS S3,SUM(T1.SR1) AS SR1, SUM(T1.SR2) AS SR2, SUM(T1.SR3) AS SR3, SUM(T1.D) AS D
FROM         (SELECT     Item, SUM(Q) AS O, 0 AS P1, 0 AS P2, 0 AS P3, 0 AS S1, 0 AS S2, 0 AS S3, 0 AS SR1, 0 AS SR2, 0 AS SR3, 0 AS D
           FROM          (SELECT     PD.Item, SUM(PD.Quantity) AS Q
           FROM          Purchase P INNER JOIN
                                  PurchaseDetails PD ON P.Invoice = PD.Invoice
           WHERE      (P.[Date] < @StartDate)
           GROUP BY PD.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     PD.Item, - (SUM(PD.Quantity)) AS Q
           FROM         Sales P INNER JOIN
                                 SalesDetails PD ON P.Invoice = PD.Invoice
           WHERE     (P.[Date] < @StartDate)
           GROUP BY PD.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     PD.Item, SUM(PD.Quantity) AS Q
           FROM         Sales P INNER JOIN
                                 SalesReturns PD ON P.Invoice = PD.Invoice
           WHERE     (PD.[Date] < @StartDate)
           GROUP BY PD.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     Item, - (SUM(Quantity)) AS Q
           FROM         Damage D
           WHERE     ([Date] < @StartDate)
           GROUP BY Item) T
           GROUP BY Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     PD.Item, 0 AS O, SUM(PD.Quantity) AS P1, 0 AS P2, 0 AS P3, 0 AS S1, 0 AS S2, 0 AS S3, 0 AS SR1, 0 AS SR2, 0 AS SR3, 0 AS D
           FROM         dbo.Purchase P INNER JOIN
                                 dbo.PurchaseDetails PD ON P.Invoice = PD.Invoice
           WHERE     (P.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate) AND (P.Company = 1)
           GROUP BY PD.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     PD.Item, 0 AS O, 0 AS P1, SUM(PD.Quantity) AS P2, 0 AS P3, 0 AS S1, 0 AS S2, 0 AS S3, 0 AS SR1, 0 AS SR2, 0 AS SR3, 0 AS D
           FROM         dbo.Purchase P INNER JOIN
                                 dbo.PurchaseDetails PD ON P.Invoice = PD.Invoice
           WHERE     (P.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate) AND (P.Company = 2)
           GROUP BY PD.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     PD.Item, 0 AS O, 0 AS P1, 0 AS P2, SUM(PD.Quantity) AS P3, 0 AS S1, 0 AS S2, 0 AS S3, 0 AS SR1, 0 AS SR2, 0 AS SR3, 0 AS D
           FROM         dbo.Purchase P INNER JOIN
                                 dbo.PurchaseDetails PD ON P.Invoice = PD.Invoice
           WHERE     (P.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate) AND (P.Company = 3)
           GROUP BY PD.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     PD.Item, 0 AS O, 0 AS P1, 0 AS P2, 0 AS P3, SUM(PD.Quantity) AS S1, 0 AS S2, 0 AS S3, 0 AS SR1, 0 AS SR2, 0 AS SR3, 0 AS D
           FROM         dbo.Sales P INNER JOIN
                                 dbo.SalesDetails PD ON P.Invoice = PD.Invoice
           WHERE     (P.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate) AND (P.Company = 1)
           GROUP BY PD.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     PD.Item, 0 AS O, 0 AS P1, 0 AS P2, 0 AS P3, 0 AS S1, SUM(PD.Quantity) AS S2, 0 AS S3, 0 AS SR1, 0 AS SR2, 0 AS SR3, 0 AS D
           FROM         dbo.Sales P INNER JOIN
                                 dbo.SalesDetails PD ON P.Invoice = PD.Invoice
           WHERE     (P.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate) AND (P.Company = 2)
           GROUP BY PD.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     PD.Item, 0 AS O, 0 AS P1, 0 AS P2, 0 AS P3, 0 AS S1, 0 AS S2, SUM(PD.Quantity) AS S3, 0 AS SR1, 0 AS SR2, 0 AS SR3, 0 AS D
           FROM         dbo.Sales P INNER JOIN
                                 dbo.SalesDetails PD ON P.Invoice = PD.Invoice
           WHERE     (P.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate) AND (P.Company = 3)
           GROUP BY PD.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     dbo.SalesReturns.Item, 0 AS O, 0 AS P1, 0 AS P2, 0 AS P3, 0 AS S1, 0 AS S2, 0 AS S3, SUM(dbo.SalesReturns.Quantity) AS SR1, 0 AS SR2, 0 AS SR3, 0 AS D
           FROM         dbo.SalesReturns INNER JOIN
                                 dbo.Sales ON dbo.SalesReturns.Invoice = dbo.Sales.Invoice
           WHERE     (dbo.SalesReturns.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate) AND (dbo.Sales.Company = 1)
           GROUP BY dbo.SalesReturns.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     dbo.SalesReturns.Item, 0 AS O, 0 AS P1, 0 AS P2, 0 AS P3, 0 AS S1, 0 AS S2, 0 AS S3, 0 AS SR1, SUM(dbo.SalesReturns.Quantity) AS SR2, 0 AS SR3, 0 AS D
           FROM         dbo.SalesReturns INNER JOIN
                                 dbo.Sales ON dbo.SalesReturns.Invoice = dbo.Sales.Invoice
           WHERE     (dbo.SalesReturns.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate) AND (dbo.Sales.Company = 2)
           GROUP BY dbo.SalesReturns.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     dbo.SalesReturns.Item, 0 AS O, 0 AS P1, 0 AS P2, 0 AS P3, 0 AS S1, 0 AS S2, 0 AS S3, 0 AS SR1, 0 AS SR2, SUM(dbo.SalesReturns.Quantity) AS SR3, 0 AS D
           FROM         dbo.SalesReturns INNER JOIN
                                 dbo.Sales ON dbo.SalesReturns.Invoice = dbo.Sales.Invoice
           WHERE     (dbo.SalesReturns.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate) AND (dbo.Sales.Company = 3)
           GROUP BY dbo.SalesReturns.Item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT     Item, 0 AS O, 0 AS P1, 0 AS P2, 0 AS P3, 0 AS S1, 0 AS S2, 0 AS S3, 0 AS SR1, 0 AS SR2, 0 AS SR3, SUM(Quantity) AS D
           FROM         dbo.Damage
           WHERE     ([Date] BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate)
           GROUP BY Item) T1 INNER JOIN
          dbo.Items ON T1.Item = dbo.Items.Code INNER JOIN (SELECT     Code, Name, SUM(CASE WHEN NETPPRICE <> 0 THEN NETPPRICE ELSE 0 END) AS NetPPrice, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN NETSPRICE <> 0 THEN NETSPRICE ELSE 0 END) AS NetSPrice, SUM(CASE WHEN Diff <> 0 THEN Diff ELSE 0 END) 
          AS Difference
          FROM         (SELECT     TOP 100 PERCENT dbo.Items.Code, dbo.Items.Name, V1.NetPPrice, V2.NetSPrice, ROUND(V2.NetSPrice - V1.NetPPrice, 2) AS Diff
          FROM          dbo.Items LEFT OUTER JOIN
          (SELECT     Item, ROUND(NetPPrice, 2) AS NetPPrice
            FROM          (SELECT     Item, AVG([Value] / Units) AS NetPPrice
          FROM          (SELECT     dbo.PurchaseDetails.Item, SUM(dbo.PurchaseDetails.Quantity * dbo.PurchaseDetails.Price) AS Value, 
         SUM(dbo.PurchaseDetails.Quantity) AS Units
          FROM          dbo.Purchase INNER JOIN
         dbo.PurchaseDetails ON dbo.Purchase.Invoice = dbo.PurchaseDetails.Invoice
          GROUP BY dbo.Purchase.[Date], dbo.PurchaseDetails.Item
          HAVING      (dbo.Purchase.[Date] <= GETDATE()) AND SUM(dbo.PurchaseDetails.Quantity)<>0) T
          GROUP BY Item) T1) V1 ON dbo.Items.Code = V1.Item LEFT OUTER JOIN
          (SELECT     Item, ROUND(NetSPrice, 2) AS NetSPrice
            FROM          (SELECT     Item, AVG([Value] / Units) AS NetSPrice
          FROM          (SELECT     dbo.SalesDetails.Item, 
         SUM(dbo.SalesDetails.Quantity * (dbo.SalesDetails.Price - dbo.SalesDetails.Discount)) AS Value, 
         SUM(dbo.SalesDetails.Quantity) AS Units
          FROM          dbo.Sales INNER JOIN
         dbo.SalesDetails ON dbo.Sales.Invoice = dbo.SalesDetails.Invoice
          GROUP BY dbo.Sales.[Date], dbo.SalesDetails.Item
                                  HAVING      (dbo.Sales.[Date] <= GETDATE())) T
          GROUP BY Item) T1) V2 ON dbo.Items.Code = V2.Item) G
          GROUP BY Code, Name
          ) T2 ON T1.Item = T2.Code
          GROUP BY T1.Item, dbo.Items.Name, T2. NetPPrice
          ORDER BY dbo.Items.Name
 End
GO
```

Comment: thanks @marc_s for editing much appretiated and noted.

Answer (score 0):

You have calculated fields being returned from your stored procedure.
All the SUM() fields in first SELECT statement

```
SUM(T1.O) AS O, SUM(T1.P1) AS P1,     SUM(T1.P2) AS P2, SUM(T1.P3) AS P3,.......
```

Comment: and what are these 'T1's and 'P2's ?

Comment: they are alias name for inner subqueries